# How to introduce a box entry to this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, pygame

I need to merge 2 codes into 1, but can't do it without freezings. One of them displays 2 random numbers on screen and the sign "+" between them and generates a gray rectangle (see this post: [How to STOP generating numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820918/how-to-stop-generating-numbers) ). Here is the final code from the first one:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Projecte MatZanfe")
font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 50)
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ''
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
running = True
def start_the_game():
    x = random.randint(0, 10)
    y = random.randint(0, 10)
    is_correct = False
    return x, y

def display_the_game(x, y):
    # Variables
    points = 0

    z = x + y
    surface.fill((255, 70, 90))
    text = font.render(str(x) + "+" + str(y), True, (255, 255, 255))
    input_rect = pygame.Rect(200, 200, 180, 50)

    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color_active, input_rect)
    text_surface = base_font.render(user_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
    surface.blit(text_surface, input_rect)
    surface.blit(text, (260, 120))
    input_rect.w = max(100, text_surface.get_width() + 10)

x, y = start_the_game()
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    display_the_game(x, y)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

The other one generates an entry box, so the user can put whatever he wants (this will be used to put the result of the sum of the numbers from the first code). Here is the code:

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
COLOR_INACTIVE = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
COLOR_ACTIVE = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 32)
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
user_text = ''


class InputBox:

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text=''):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.color = COLOR_INACTIVE
        self.text = text
        self.txt_surface = FONT.render(text, True, self.color)
        self.active = False

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # Toggle the active variable.
                self.active = not self.active
            else:
                self.active = False
            # Change the current color of the input box.
            self.color = COLOR_ACTIVE if self.active else COLOR_INACTIVE
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    print(self.text)
                    self.text = ''
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                # Re-render the text.
                self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)

    def update(self):
        # Resize the box if the text is too long.
        width = max(200, self.txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        self.rect.w = width

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x+5, self.rect.y+5))
        # Blit the rect.
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 2)



def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    input_box2 = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)
    input_boxes = [input_box2]
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            for box in input_boxes:
                box.handle_event(event)

        for box in input_boxes:
            box.update()

        screen.fill((255, 70, 90))
        for box in input_boxes:
            box.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

I need to merge them into 1 code, so the user can give the answer for the random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have the file with the class `InputBox` named:
`InputBox.py`. go to the **other file** with the 2 random numbers and change it to this:

```
import pygame
import random
from InputBox import InputBox

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Projecte MatZanfe")
font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 50)
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ''
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
running = True


def start_the_game():
    x = random.randint(0, 10)
    y = random.randint(0, 10)
    is_correct = False
    return x, y

def display_the_game(x, y):
    # Variables
    points = 0

    z = x + y
    surface.fill((255, 70, 90))
    text = font.render(str(x) + "+" + str(y), True, (255, 255, 255))

    text_surface = base_font.render(user_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
    surface.blit(text, (260, 120))
    input_box.draw(surface)

x, y = start_the_game()
input_box = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)

while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        else:
            result = input_box.handle_event(event)
            if result != None:
                if int(result) == x + y:
                    # TODO: add what you want to do when he is right
                    pass
                else:
                    # TODO: add what you want to do when the use is wrong
                    pass

    display_the_game(x, y)        # By the way you can take all of the code in this function and move to the main loop, looks cleaner to me
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Now take a note of 3 things:

1. You need to add the code when the user is right, what you want to do, and when he is wrong, what you want to do, I didn't add this.
2. I didn't check if the user input is valid. I called `int()` function on his input, so if he enters a string there will be an exception thrown.
3. I changed a bit the `handle_event` function on the `InputBox` file, so it will return the result, and won't print it. Now it looks like this:

```
    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # Toggle the active variable.
                self.active = not self.active
            else:
                self.active = False
            # Change the current color of the input box.
            self.color = COLOR_ACTIVE if self.active else COLOR_INACTIVE
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    user_input = self.text
                    self.text = ''
                    self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)
                    return user_input
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                # Re-render the text.
                self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)
```

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try. Thanks, I will try to complete it.